# Flutter / Firebase - My iOS device will not connect to firebase / firestore while on WiFi

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, wifi

My Flutter app I have been working on will not retrieve data only when it IS connected to wifi.  It times out after 10 seconds.  My cell phone it works fine.  When I run the app on an the simulator from my computer it works fine on wifi.  I am not sure if there is some setting I need to have changed or what...

I have restarted my phone, computer, router and same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case this helps someone else.  I was able to get my iPhone to connect to firebase over WiFi after I turned off the "Private Address" toggle button.

*Using a private address helps reduce tracking of your iPhone across different Wi-Fi networks*

Settings App > WiFi > Select the connected wifi name > turned off Private Address.

After I did this it started working.  I tried few more times with it on and off and eventually it started to work both ways.  Maybe it was just renewing the IP address info I am not sure.  I did restart my devices prior to doing this and it didn't fix it.